# C++ Simple hangman game

Tags: c++, string

Hi so i have started c++ 3 days ago, read some tutorials etc. I wanted to make my own hangman game since it seemed as an easy task for a begginer but i stumbled upon an issue. Everything is working well ecept i cant seem to find a way to make 1 letter strings swap with underscores until underscores change to the missing word. So basically when you compile it you can guess the whole word only.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string player1,player2,word,underscore,guess;
int wrong=0;
int main (){
string copy = word;


cout << "----------------------Hello! Welcome to the HANGMAN game!----------  ----------" << endl;
cout << "Please type in your name, PLAYER 1" << endl;
cin >> player1;
cout << "Please type in your name, PLAYER 2" << endl;
cin >> player2;
cout << "OK " << player1 << " and " << player2 << ". Let's start with the    game!" << endl;
cout << player1 << " please input the word you want " << player2 << " to guess." << endl;

cin >> word;

//space
for (int x=0; x<30; x++){
cout << endl;
}

//UNDERSCORE
while (underscore.size() != word.size()){
underscore.push_back('_');}

cout << underscore << endl;

//MAIN WHILE
while(wrong<12){
cin >> guess;

//IF GUESS ISNT LETTER
if(guess.size() > 1){
if(guess==word){
cout << "Thats the right word." << endl;
break;
}
else{
cout << underscore << endl;
cout << "Wrong word try again." << endl;
cout << "Used: " << usedguess << endl;
wrong ++;
}

    }





if(underscore == word){
  cout << "You win!" << endl;
  break;
}



if(wrong==1){
cout << "I" << endl;
}
else if(wrong==2){
cout << "I" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
}
else if(wrong==3){
cout << "I" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
}
else if(wrong==4){
cout << "I" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
}
else if(wrong==5){
cout << "I" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
}
else if(wrong==6){
cout << "I===" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
}
else if(wrong==7){
cout << "I===" << endl;
cout << "I  O" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
}
else if(wrong==8){
cout << "I===" << endl;
cout << "I  O" << endl;
cout << "I  |" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
}
else if(wrong==9){
cout << "I===" << endl;
cout << "I  O" << endl;
cout << "I -|" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
}
else if(wrong==10){
cout << "I===" << endl;
cout << "I  O" << endl;
cout << "I -|-" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
}
else if(wrong==11){
cout << "I===" << endl;
cout << "I  O" << endl;
cout << "I -|-" << endl;
cout << "I /"  << endl;
cout << "I" << endl;
}
else if(wrong==12){
cout << "I===" << endl;
cout << "I  O" << endl;
cout << "I -|-" << endl;
cout << "I / /"<< endl;
cout << "I YOU ARE DEAD" << endl;

cout << "Game over bro! The word was: " << word <<endl;
break;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for downvoting and not even giving a reason for it...

Comment: Instead of `if (condition1) else if (condition2) (...) else` is better to use switch case statements. Check here, for instance: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson5.html.

Comment: (1) Learn to indent. Please. It will make everything so much easier. (2) You don't have any code that comes remotely close to letting the user guess a single letter at a time, so why are you expecting to be able to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare the strings of `word` and `guess`, you can iterate over the characters in a for-loop, and check if there is a match

```
string word  = "hangman";
string guess = "mansomething";
string underscore = string(word.size(), '_'); // init a string with underscores equal to the length of 'word'

// iterate over the characters in word and guess
for (size_t i = 0, iend = min(word.size(), guess.size()); i < iend; i++) {
    if (word[i] == guess[i])
        underscore[i] = word[i];  // if the characters match at position i, update the underscore.
}

cout << underscore << endl;
```

Afterwards, `underscore` contains the following

```
_an____
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I have been looking for this for hours. I would upvote you but my reputation is only 12 since i have recieved some downvotes asking questions...

Comment: I tried your solution and there is another problem. Using your code the position of the letter in the guess matters. I need the program to be able to take singleletter guesses and scan the whole word for the guess.

Comment: @TheNoob You could use the [std::string:find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) function to determine the position of a character in a string, it returns -1 if the character is not found, and the index otherwise. I will leave the implementation as an exercise for you ;p

Comment: thanks for this information gonna start right now :D